# Cooking ham and scalloped potatoes

Tags: baking

At what temperature can you cook scalloped potatoes and heat a cooked ham together? Ham says 275 and potatoes says 325.

Answer (score 4):

I would stick to approx 300, and put the potatoes in the hottest part of the oven and the ham in the coolest part of the oven, that should do the trick, and get ready to take your ham out before the potatoes are finished - at which point possibly turn the oven up a bit.  As with a lot of cooking, it can take a bit of juggling.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this but it's perfectly sensible advice and normal behaviour. If you disagree with something, you should say what.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I wonder if it was the temperature recommendation they didn't like.  I would follow this advice, but I would start at 275, pull the ham when it's done and turn the oven up to 325 while the ham is resting for the potatoes to finish.

Comment: @senschen.  Yes I thought of that and possibly that is the better advice.  It does all depend upon what type of oven, fan etc...