# Cooking time and temperature for one oven and two different dishes

Tags: cooking-time

I want to warm a 9.6lb spiral ham (275- 15 minutes per lb) and cook a macaroni and cheese casserole (375 for about 30-45 min) in the same oven and have them ready at the same time.  How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cooking ham and scalloped potatoes](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/80910/cooking-ham-and-scalloped-potatoes)

Comment: It's true that we'd probably benefit from a canonical question about this sort of thing, and at that point would be able to close many things as duplicates. But since it's not a one-size-fits-all thing (larger vs smaller temperature gaps, things that benefit from being served soon after baking, etc), individual specific questions like that proposed one tend not to make good duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

1. Heat ham at 275.
2. Remove ham and hold. Covered with foil and maybe towels to hold heat.
3. Raise oven temp, bake mac & cheese.
4. Ham should still be warm when mac and cheese done.

If it were me, I'd return the ham to the oven for the last fifteen minutes or so to crisp the skin a bit with the higher temperature.

Answer (score 1):

The ham (not a spiral) I did yesterday said 350 for 10-15 minutes per lb.
My Mac & cheese recipe (BH&G) bakes at 350 for 35-40 minutes.

I would cover the ham with foil, bake it at 350, and put the mac & cheese in the oven for the last 35 minutes.

I didn't do them both yesterday, but if I did, that's probably how I'd do it.